# #DocuSignAPI and using the CRCL parameter

Tags: docusignapi

I have a question about the CRCL parameter in a Custom Related List using the #DocuSignAPI.

Besides the example listed in the documentation, does anyone have any examples to share?  Does this mean this button can be put on a related list in Salesforce and be able to mass send?  Does it mass send to all at once??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are referring to Custom Button Logic in DocuSign for Salesforce. The CRCL parameter allows the selection of recipients from a custom list related to the object where the button is placed.

The parameters do not affect the placement of the button. This is handled by placing the button in the Salesforce "layout".

If your goal is to send documents to many recipients you can either hard code the recipients in the CRL parameter, load default contacts from the object or use CRCL to define recipients from a custom list related to the object.

Here is Custom Button code sample to send to multiple hard coded 
recipients using the CRL parameter.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
//*************************************************//
CCRM = 'Signer 1~Signer 1;Signer 2~Signer 2;Signer 3~Signer 3';
CCTM =  'Signer 1~Signer;Signer 2~Signer;Signer 3~CarbonCopy';
CRL = 'Email~sam@sample.com;FirstName~Sam;LastName~Sample;Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1;Email~{!Opportunity.OwnerEmail};FirstName~Sally;LastName~Simple;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2;Email~sue@simple.com;FirstName~Sue;LastName~Simple;Role~Signer 3;RoutingOrder~3';

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********//
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
```

Comment: I posted this question way back months ago before I really new much about the Custom Button Logic.  I was looking for alternative method in sending the same document to Multiple recipients - instead of using the Bulk Sending feature with a CSV file that you have to upload to DocuSign.  The Custom Button Javascript button will not do that.

We could use Conga Composer and their mass email functionality, but I was trying to avoid another app being installed.  

The only option is to use the CSV file, upload to DocuSign and have custom fields that send data back to Salesforce.